# Asynctask doesn't download all the content

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I created this code for downloading web content and i used asynctask. When the url adress start with "http" it doesn't return me anythink only error in log cat.

> *"09-12 22:19:25.679 6894-6921/company.krystian.guessthecelebrity W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>
> 09-12 22:19:25.754 6894-6921/company.krystian.guessthecelebrity E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
>       glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da"*

But when the URL adress start with "https" it return me a part of content and another error.

> *"09-12 22:13:36.330 3057-3784/company.krystian.guessthecelebrity W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>
> 09-12 22:13:36.390 3057-3784/company.krystian.guessthecelebrity E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
>       glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da"*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }
            return result;


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return "Fail";

        }




    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;

    try {

        result = task.execute("http://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/").get();

        Log.i("Contents of URL", result);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}
```

Comment: Just paste errors here insteed of images

Comment: THose are unrelated messages from the GPU.

Comment: Oh and NEVER use asynctask.execute().get().  Especially not on the UI thread.  It will stall your app, you're probably being killed by the watchdog timer.  Any code there that needs the result should be placed in onPostExecute instead.  (there's times its ok on a non-UI thread, but that's so vanishingly small that unless you know what you're doing, just don't do it).

Answer (score 1):

This is my working code snipped please:

```
private class GetRegisterDateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("YOUR URL HERE");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(inputLine);
            }

            in.close();

            result = buffer.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
            return "";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
            return "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
            return "";
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
             // check and use the result here
             ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the calling code:

```
  GetRegisterDateAsyncTask registerDateAsyncTask = new GetRegisterDateAsyncTask();
        registerDateAsyncTask.execute();
```

Good luck )

Comment: It also return only part of content.

Comment: all the time the same content or different contents ?

Comment: All the time the same content, depends on the website, sometimes its 5 line, sometimes 25% of full content.

Comment: it could mean there are defer loading parts of the page

Comment: I have just tried your URL case and all is OK - all the content is retrieved successfully, there may be something else in your app, which could block the execution of the task

Comment: to be ensured please create a new project and test this task only please

Comment: I did new project and it's the same situation

Comment: It seams there is something wrong in your dev environment. Do you use Android Studio? I can send my  working project to you if you give me some email please,